# Problem : Normal form of product of matrices over a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm looking for some assistance on the following problem from Jacobon's "Basic Algebra 1" (#5, p. 194):

Let $A, B \in M_n(D)$ satisfy det $AB \ne 0$ ($D$ a PID.)  Let diag$\{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\}$, diag$\{b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n\}$, and diag$\{c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n\}$ be normal forms for $A$, $B$, and $AB$ respectively.  Prove $a_i | c_i$ and $b_i | c_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$.

Comment: Theorem II.14 in Morris Newman, *Integral matrices*, Academic Press 1972. The proof doesn't look like it's easily summarized.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I'll check this out.